# Remove the outer of nested dictionary key in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a nested dictionary in python - 
{a: {d:{v:2, c:3}}}
and I want to write a function that getting a key - like 'a' 
and return a dictionary: 
{d:{v:2, c:3}}
just the inside

I try to use:

```
def findkeys(node, kv):
    if isinstance(node, list):
        for i in node:
            for x in findkeys(i, kv):
               yield x
    elif isinstance(node, dict):
        if kv in node:
            yield node[kv]
        for j in node.values():
            for x in findkeys(j, kv):
                yield x
```

But it is return it as a list and not a dictionary so it has only one- item in the list `[{d:{v:2, c:3}}]` so I cant get access after it to key 'c' for example

My dictionary preasent a tree and I want to go thruogh it until I will get to a leaf.

Someone has an idea?

Comment: As you've described it, you `outerdict['a']` would give you the inner dict

Comment: You can also do list[0] after calling your function, although this seems like an unnecessary step.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
def get_val(dct,key):
    for k, v in dct.iteritems():
        if key in dct.keys():
            print dct[key]
        else :
            for d in dct.values():
                get_val(d, key)

dct = {'a': {'d':{'v':2, 'c':3}}}
key='a'
get_val(dct,key)
```

if `key='a'`, output=`{'d':{'v':2, 'c':3}}`
if `key='d'`, output =`{'c': 3, 'v': 2}`